# Center an image horizontally using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a image horizontally using css.

I am displaying my image on the screen with the following HTML code:

```
<div id="loading" class="loading-invisible">  
    <img class="loading" src="logo.png">
</div>
```

I am croping my image as I only want to display some of the image and I am using the following css:

```
img.loading 
{
position:absolute;
clip:rect(0px,681px,75px,180px);
}
```

however I can't work out how to center the image once it has been croped.

Anyone able to help ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use position absolute and margin like this

```
img.loading{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -(half ot the image width)px
}
```

Comment: ...or rather position: relative?

Answer (score 150):

Try this for your CSS:

```
.center img {        
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

and then add to your image to center it:

```
class="center"
```

Comment: This solution will not work when the img must be set with `position:absolute;`

Comment: In my situation I had to use `display:contents` instead of `block`

Answer (score 19):

You can use different method:

**Method 1:**

Its a simple method, use "`text-align: center;`"  for your parent div.

```css
#loading {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="loading-invisible">  
    <img class="loading" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=Logo">
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shuozj31/)

**Method 2:**

Please check the code:

```css
#loading img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  float: none; 
  /*width: 200px; if its a large image, it need a width for align center*/
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="loading-invisible">  
    <img class="loading" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=Logo">
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/12o5d608/4/)

**Method 3:**

Using "`display: flex;`"

```css
#loading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="loading-invisible">  
    <img class="loading" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=Logo">
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ch18knuz/)

**Method 4:**

You can use "`position: absolute;`",

```css
#loading {
        position: relative;
        }
#loading img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="loading-invisible">  
    <img class="loading" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.png&text=Logo">
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uazr2ox6/1/)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `margin`

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: I believe you'll also want a `display:block;` for an img tag.

Comment: You'd also have to give it a width for that to work. You could also give the wrapper `text-align: center;` and that itself would center the image as long as you don't change the `display` to something else than `inline`.

Comment: Suggest width: auto;

Answer (score -1):

Ways:

1. Setting Left and Right Margin to “auto”
2. Using display "Flex"
3. Using the Text Align property

You can take a look on this blog for more descriptive answer

https://ecedev.com/post/How%20to%20center%20an%20image%20horizontally%20using%20HTML%20and%20CSS

Comment: helpfulUser, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)