# Text-align not working with img

Tags: html, css

I have a website and i've centered some images using `text-align`.

Now in my main content `div`, i am trying to center an `img` and it's not working.

```
<div id="Content" style="width:100%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;top:66px;bottom:200px;">
   <img src="myimg.png" style="text-align: center;" />
</div>
```

That's all there is to it. Why will all other images center, but not this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `text-align` on `img` tag, use it on `div` tag:

```
<div id="Content" style="width:100%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;top:66px;bottom:200px;text-align: center;">
   <img src="myimg.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`text-align: center` needs to be applied to the parent element, in your case, the `div`:

```
<div id="Content" style="width:100%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;top:66px;bottom:200px;text-align: center;">
   <img src="myimg.png" />
</div>
```

Though I strongly discourage the use of inline CSS, so if you have a stylesheet, move it there:

```css
#Content {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:66px;
    bottom:200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Another way to do it is the automatically distribute the margins around the element, but this will only work for block-level elements:

```css
#Content > img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The way you have set the tag up would imply that the content within the image tag would be center aligned. Images have no content, so it does nothing instead.

Comment: I'm applying the style to the `div` element, not the `img` element. The content of the `div` element includes an image.

Answer (score 1):

Text align center should be your div characteristic rather than img.

```
<div id="Content" style=" text-align: center; width:100%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;top:66px;bottom:200px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto margins for this:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

More reading: [w3](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

or, if you know the width of the image:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -(half ot the image width)px
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856150/css-to-center-a-image-horizontally)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using inline CSS, they are bad to do on websites because search engines take it negatively, always try to use a different stylesheet for the CSS. You can use the code as rink attendant gave.

And text-align can only be used in block containers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only used inline because it was quick and easy for making the question.